# Linq to object Right outer join

Tags: c#, linq

I have written following linq query but I am not getting expected result.My Expected result is all the matching record bettween lst and list and all the non matching record from list
 for example.

I want following result

**a,b,c,d,e,f**

```
public class Com : IEqualityComparer<DuplicateData>
    {
        public bool Equals(DuplicateData x, DuplicateData y)
        {
            return x.address.Equals(y.address);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(DuplicateData obj)
        {
            return obj.address.GetHashCode();

        }
    }

static void Run ()
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    lst.Add("a");
    lst.Add("b");
    lst.Add("c");
    lst.Add("p");

    List<DuplicateData> list = new List<DuplicateData>()
    {
        new DuplicateData{address="a"},
        new DuplicateData{address="a"},
        new DuplicateData{address="a"},
        new DuplicateData{address="b"},
        new DuplicateData{address="b"},
        new DuplicateData{address="c"},
        new DuplicateData{address="d"},
        new DuplicateData{address="e"},
        new DuplicateData{address="f"},
    };

    var dup = list.Distinct(new Com());
    var RightJoin = from x in dup
                    join y in lst
                    on x.address equals y
                    into right
                    from z in right
                    select new
                    {
                        UniqueAddress = z,

                    };

}
```

Comment: I am using custom comparar to remove duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var RightJoin = from x in dup
                join y in lst
                on x.address equals y
                into right
                from z in right.DefaultIfEmpty(x.address)
                select new
                {
                    UniqueAddress = z,
                };
```

result is (a,b,c,d,e,f)

Working sample: http://ideone.com/MOIhZH

---

**Explanation**

*To make a left/right join in linq you have to use [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx) method, that will yield (default) result when there is no match (the joined result is empty). However, default value for string is `null` so you have to provide default value from the "left side" collection to see it in the result set.*

---

**Alternative approach**

*This is probably more convenient approach. Instead of selecting from `z` and providing the default value, you will select from `x.address` - the left side of the join.*

```
var RightJoin = from x in dup
                join y in lst
                on x.address equals y
                into right
                from z in right.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    UniqueAddress = x.address,
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var res = from x in list
          join y in lst on x.address equals y into right 
          from xy in right.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new { UniqueAddress = xy };
```

result:

```
{ UniqueAddress = a },
{ UniqueAddress = a },
{ UniqueAddress = a },
{ UniqueAddress = b },
{ UniqueAddress = b },
{ UniqueAddress = c },
{ UniqueAddress = null },
{ UniqueAddress = null },
{ UniqueAddress = null }
```

Comment: It's not the excepted result my expected result is (a,b,c,d,e,f)